# Как при установке Docker Desktop for Windows указать другой каталог установки?

Tags: windows, docker, install

Есть ли у "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" параметры командной строки для указания каталога установки?
Или ткните в документацию, на https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/ такого не нашел.

Comment: Я качнул установщик, распаковал его, но там exe тоже не хотят делиться справкой, а текстовые файлы не содержат переменных про пусть установки.

Comment: Если запускать установщик в консоли, выводится сообщение: d:\var\downloads>[11:17:22.186] [ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader] **No install path specified**, looking for default installation registry key
[11:17:24.757] [Program] Existing installation found: version=50684, displayVersion=3.0.0, basePath=C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker, channel=, channelUrl=https://desktop.docker.com/win/stable/appcast.xml"
Т.е. каким-то образом задать install path можно. Но мне не удалось подобрать такие параметры cli

Comment: А `basePath` не?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

If using the Windows Command Prompt:
start /w "" "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install

--installation-dir=: changes the default installation location (C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker)

Допустим, нужно установить в папку **"D:\Docker"**, тогда:

В папке, куда скачали "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" запускаем CMD и выполняем команду:

**"Docker Desktop Installer.exe" install --installation-dir="D:\Docker"**

;)